# Web page content is often shaken at refresh (firefox)

Tags: html, css, firefox, display

I am very far from a web designer / website writter. I just try for a small app with esp8266 ethernet shield to writte a web page to print sensors results.

On an online html editor, everything works perfectly, but with my esp8266, the page content is shaken at **almost every** refresh when using firefox (works well on Microsoft edge). Curious that it is not every time...

Here is the base code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='fr'> 
<head> 
    <meta charset='UTF-8'> 
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'> 
    <title>Number Input</title> 
    <style> 
        body { 
            background-color: #044a88; 
            display: flex; 
            font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif; 
            justify-content: center; 
            align-items: center; 
            height: 100vh; 
            margin: 0; 
        } 
        .container { 
            background-color: #EFEFEF; 
            padding: 25px; 
            border-radius: 10px; 
        } 
        .logo { 
            display: block; 
            margin-left: auto; 
            margin-right: auto; 
            margin-bottom: 30px; 
            width: 80%; 
        } 
        h1 { 
        font-size: 20px; 
        } 
        h2 { 
        font-size: 22px; 
            padding-top: 20px; 
            font-weight: bold; 
        } 
        table { 
            width: 100%; 
            border-collapse: collapse; 
        } 
        .param_th { 
        font-size: 16px; 
        padding-top: 10px; 
            padding-right: 20px; 
            text-align: right; 
            border: none; 
            font-weight: normal; 
        } 
        .param_td { 
        padding-right: 0px; 
            padding-left: 1px; 
            padding-top: 10px; 
            text-align: left; 
            border: none; 
            font-weight: normal; 
        }         
        .batt_td { 
            padding: 8px; 
            padding-right: 80px; 
            text-align: left; 
            border: none; 
            font-weight: bold; 
        } 
        .batt_th { 
        text-align: right; 
            font-weight: normal; 
        } 
        input[type='number'] { 
            width: 60px; 
        } 
        button[type='submit'] { 
            display: block;  
            padding: 2px; 
            padding-right: 6px; 
            padding-left: 6px; 
            margin-top: 10px; 
            margin: 30px auto 0 auto; 
        } 
    </style> 
</head>

<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='5'>

<body>  
    <div class='container'>  
        <img data-testid="image-asset" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1269432564/fr/vectoriel/polices-dalphabet-modernes-minimales-typographie-minimaliste-urban-digital-fashion.jpg?s=1024x1024&amp;w=is&amp;k=20&amp;c=Gpvmuq6Xl4shU7hLdzknSXuD5LYKQmjAjiObAkOYg_w=" style="max-height:200px;max-width:70%;object-fit:scale-down;width:auto;height:auto" fetchpriority="high" class='logo'>
        <h2>Batt</h2>  
        <table>  
            <tbody>  
                <tr>  
                    <td class='batt_td'>John Doe</td>  
                    <th class='batt_th'>New York</th>  
                </tr>  
                <tr>  
                    <td class='batt_td'>Jane Smith</td>  
                    <th class='batt_th'>Los Angeles</th>  
                </tr>  
                <tr>  
                    <td class='batt_td'>Michael Johnson</td>  
                    <th class='batt_th'>Chicago</th>  
                </tr>  
            </tbody>  
        </table>  
        <h2>Box</h2>  
        <table>  
            <tbody>  
                <tr>  
                    <td class='batt_td'>John Doe</td>  
                    <th class='batt_th'>New York</th>  
                </tr>  
                <tr>  
                    <td class='batt_td'>Jane Smith</td>  
                    <th class='batt_th'>Los Angeles</th>  
                </tr>  
                <tr>  
                    <td class='batt_td'>Michael Johnson</td>  
                    <th class='batt_th'>Chicago</th>  
                </tr>  
            </tbody>  
        </table>  
    </div>  
</body>
```

I tried to fix the content with `position: absolute` and `top: 200px` for example, but I need to put the content at the center of the page by default. Not with absolute values.

Please, do you know how to fix that?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Have a good day!

Comment: I use:   client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
  client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
  client.println("Connection: close"); 
  client.println(); Then send HTML

Comment: PS: I can't add "Hello everyone!" to the post... Sorry for that

Comment: I think it's the image. Firefox renders the white container twice, once without the image, and once with, whereas other browser only perform the last render. You could include the image in the source code using base64, in my tests that works a lot better. See: https://www.base64-image.de/